# How do i force links in a dynamic object to open in a new tab?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, rss

I'm trying to load up a styled RSS feed from my WordPress blog on another site, and I can load it up just fine, but the security of WordPress does not allow you to open their site in a frame. So can anyone tell me how to change the target attribute of the links in the styled RSS feed, so that they don't try to open the wordpress site in the frame it was loaded into, but a new tab instead?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>

    <style>
        object {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;   
        }

        #content {
            height: 99%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>​
    <script>
        $("#content").html('<object data="articlefeed.html" />');
        $("#content").find('a').attr("target", "_blank");
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Article Feed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
/* begin styles for RSS Feed */

.rss-box {
     /* margin: 1em; */
     width: 800px;
     font-size: 16px;
     background-color: #D6D9DC;
     border: 0px solid #cc3300;
     direction: ltr;
     border-radius: 5px;     
}

.rss-items {
    margin-top:1px;
    padding:0.5em; 0.5em;
    /* margin-left:1px; */
    color:#333;
    direction: ltr;
}

p.rss-title {
    padding:0.5em; 
    direction: ltr;
}

.rss-title {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 85%;
    background-color:#2e353d;
    color:#f6f5f4;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0em;
    text-align: left;
    direction: ltr;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.rss-item  {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-weight : normal;
  list-style:none;
  padding-bottom:1em;
  direction: ltr;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #FFF;
}

.rss-item a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#000000;
    font-size: 105%;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:verdana;
    direction: ltr;
    line-height: 150%;
}

.rss-item a:visited {
    color:#448822;
    direction: ltr;
}

.rss-date {
    font-size: 85%;
    font-weight : normal;
    color: #333;
    direction: rtl;
}
.rss-item-auth {    
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fnyhederwp.oneclick.holdbarhest.dk%2Fcategory%2Fartikler%2Ffeed%2F&chan=y&num=5&desc=200&au=y&date=y&utf=y"  charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"></script>

<noscript>
<a href="http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fnyhederwp.oneclick.holdbarhest.dk%2Fcategory%2Fartikler%2Ffeed%2F&chan=y&num=5&desc=200&au=y&date=y&utf=y&html=y">View RSS feed</a>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inside articlefeed.html the `targ`-parameter for the script:

http://www.feedroll.com/rssviewer/feed2js.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fnyhederwp.oneclick.holdbarhest.dk%2Fcategory%2Fartikler%2Ffeed%2F&chan=y&num=5&desc=200&au=y&date=y&utf=y&targ=_blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use this structure:

```
$("#content a").attr('target','_blank');
```